# Socket.io with React behaves weirdly after 5 messages

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, sockets

I am trying to build a basic chat application using socket.io and react but have ran into a weird problem. The app works like it is expected to for the first 5 messages and then after that the 6th message takes too long to load and often some of the previous messages don't show up in the chat box. Would be glad if someone could help.
Here is the code I have for backend:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const http = require('http').createServer(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(http);

io.on('connection', socket => {
  socket.on('message', ({ name, message }) => {
    io.emit('message', { name, message });
    console.log(message);
    console.log(name);
  });
});

http.listen(4000, function () {
  console.log('listening on port 4000');
});
```

Here is the code I have in my App.js:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import io from 'socket.io-client';

const App = props => {
  const socket = io.connect('http://localhost:4000');
  const [details, setDetails] = useState({ name: '', message: '' });
  const [chat, setChat] = useState([]);


  useEffect(() => {
    socket.on('message', ({ name, message }) => {
      setChat([...chat, { name, message }]); //same as {name:name,message:message}
    });
  });

  const onMessageSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const { name, message } = details;
    socket.emit('message', { name, message });
    setDetails({ name, message: '' });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={onMessageSubmit}>
        <input
          type='text'
          value={details.name}
          onChange={e => setDetails({ ...details, name: e.target.value })}
        />
        <input
          type='text'
          value={details.message}
          onChange={e => setDetails({ ...details, message: e.target.value })}
        />
        <button>Send</button>
      </form>
      <ul>
        {chat &&
          chat.map((chat, index) => (
            <li key={index}>
              {chat.name}:{chat.message}
            </li>
          ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because every time, you update the state, useEffect callback runs, basically you subscribe to `message` again and again.

And after few iterations, you've multiple subscriptions trying to update the same state. And because of the `setState`'s asynchronous nature, you're seeing the weird behavior.

You need to subscribe only once, you can do that by passing empty dependency argument to `useEffect` which will make it work like `componentDidMount`

```
 useEffect(() => {
    socket.on('message', ({ name, message }) => {
      setChat([...chat, { name, message }]);
    });
  }, []);
```

Edit - To handle the **asynchronity** and take in account the previous chat, you need to `setState` via callback

```
useEffect(() => {
  socket.on("message", ({ name, message }) => {
    setChat((prevChat) => prevChat.concat([{ name, message }]));
  });
}, []);
```

You might want to `cleanup` when your component un-mounts. Please have a look at the [official docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#effects-with-cleanup).

Comment: But if now `useEffect` won't be running after each state update then how will the chat update with the latest message when a message is sent by the server?

Comment: `socket.on('message',...` should take care of that, it should run the callback you provided, every time you receive a message

Comment: I made the changes. But now the previous chat is not shown. Just the current message is displayed.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But just to make sure I've understood the entire process correctly, so what is happening is that useEffect just gets executed once and connects us to 'message'. Once we've been connected everytime a socket io emits a message the callback provided to socket.on executes where we update the state. What was wrong in the previous method of updation was that we didn't receive the chat since it's an Asynchronous task so we used to just use the spread operator on an empty array and just add the current message which lead to only the current message being shown. After the edit we now...

Comment: ... wait to receive the prevChat and then add the new message to it. This it it right? Please correct me if I'm wrong. I'm a bit new to this. Thanks for the help. Much appreciated.

Comment: Right, I just want to clarify one thing, `setState` works in batches, i.e. if you're updating the same property in the state again and again, `setState({a: 1}); setState({a: 2}) setState({a: 3})` only the latest update will reflect(in your component you might not ever see `a` getting updated to 1 or 2), even if you update `setState` with a callback, it'll still run in batches but it will take in account previously calculated state. The actual `setState` call that would be triggered would basically look something like this `setState(cb(cb(cb(currentState))))`